# Highcharts - how to put bubble chart in straight line?

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I am using Highcharts and want to create a bubble chart who's entries are all in a straight line at equally depreciating bubble sizes. The trick is making it so there is hardly any space inbetween the bubbles. Like this

[image]

Is there an easy way to do this besides writing some sort of algorithm to place it along the x-axis at a certain point?

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is not a built in option for this, no.  You'd have to calculate the size/x axis relationship yourself.

On the other hand, I feel obligated to point out that this is terrible way to present data.
Popular, but terrible.

The less popular but much better alternative is a simple horizontal bar chart, which will allow much better readibility all around.

Some discussion on the reasons why:

- http://www.perceptualedge.com/example18.php
- http://www.perceptualedge.com/blog/?p=1532

---

**{{EDIT::**

I set one up manually, just to work out the `thought process`:

- http://jsfiddle.net/jlbriggs/D3LqV/

The basic idea:

- Set your x axis min and max so that 1 x axis unit = 1 pixel of plot width, for ease of calculation
- instead of using the bubble series type, use the scatter, and for each point, specify a marker radius value (in pixels. this is the 'old' way before the bubble was a series type)
- you calculate your radii by determining a maximum pixel size you want for your largest bubble, then dividing your encoded value (the $, or whatever) by the maximum value, and multiplying by your max pixel size for each value.
- you then calculate your x value accordingly  - in my example, max pixel radius is 50.  First data point has x value of 50.  second data point has an x value of 100 + it's radius pixel value, etc...

If you look through the example, and make sure your pixel width and x axis settings correlate, the math is pretty simple arithmetic.  Writing a loop to do it all should only be a little more complicated.

**{{edit again:  took a stab**
Rough, but works, more or less...

- http://jsfiddle.net/jlbriggs/xe82d/

{and once more:
this one accounts for the width of the chart automatically:

- http://jsfiddle.net/jlbriggs/yM9jt/

Comment: I did answer the question very directly: there is no way to do this besides writing something to calculate the placement yourself.

Comment: Unfortunately I am just the front-end guy, and this is the design :) What sort of algorithm would you use? I have been experimenting some but can't come up with one that works :(